# How to retrieve image from pointer using java/Jna

Tags: java, image, buffer, arrays, jna

i want to retrieve a scanned image from a Pointer. i have the front image which is a `PointerByReference`, i used a buffer for that :

```
    Pointer p = frontimg.getValue();
    byte[] buffer = p.getByteArray(0, frontimg.getValue().SIZE);
    System.out.println(buffer);
```

when i use to read the image, it seems to be Null.

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
```

so i can't write it of course:

```
    ImageIO.write(img, "BMP", new File("D:\test.bmp"));
```

so please, what kind of method i have to use to proceed ?

Comment: `frontimg.getValue().SIZE` is the size of a pointer on the current system, *not* the size of your image data, which you'll likely need to obtain via whatever API you're calling.

Comment: i have img_util.dll, may be its the solution :) i will try it tomorrow and see what do we obtain ;) thanks a lot.